# type client null is not assignable to IntrinsicAttributes and { Children: ReactNode nextjs

Tags: next.js, jsx

I have shareable nextjs component that accepts client property

```
const ClientInfo: NextPage = ({ client }: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
```

And in my list component I am using the component as markup like this

```
{
    selectedClient && <div className={styles.clientDetail}>
        <ClientInfo client={selectedClient}></ClientInfo>
    </div>
 }
```

and this is initial `selectedClient`

```
const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState(null);
```

I tried setting `{}` instead of null, but this shows the error

```
Type '{ client:null}; is not assignable to IntrinsicAttributes  and { Children: ReactNode}

Property 'client' does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes  and { Children: ReactNode}
```

Comment: You are using `ClientInfo` like a `React.FC` then why are you using `NextPage` as its type? Define it like this: `const ClientInfo: React.FC<{ client: any }> = ({ client }) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set types for functional components props in Nextjs with TypeScript, you can use either an interface or type alias then pass that as the type parameter to the NextPage generic type.

```
import { NextPage } from "next";

// Props interface with client set to any
interface Props {
  client: any;
}

const ClientInfo: NextPage<Props> = (props) => {
  // using destructuring to get client
  const { client } = props;

};

export default ClientInfo;
```